# How to make sum of columns and sum of rows method for Two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

So far I have a method that totals the columns, but it's not exactly what I need.

I need to have the total of each row to the right of each row, and the total of each column at the bottom of each column.  Something like this

```
1  2  3  4  =  10
3  4  5  6  =  18

4  6  8  10  < - Total
```

What I have now gives me the total of each column, but not under the columns.

Method

```
    // method to add the sum of columns
    public static int[] columnSum(int x[][]){
          int temp[] = new int[x[0].length];

            for (int i = 0; i < x[0].length; i++){
                int sum = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
                    sum += x[j][i];

                }
                temp[i] = sum;
                System.out.println("Index is: " + i + " Sum is: "+sum);

            }

            return temp;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This is the array
1   2   3   
2   3   4 
3   5   7
```

apply just one more **for** loop after printing the matrix.

```
System.out.println("This is the sum of the columns");
int temp[]=columnSum(firstarray);
for(int i=0;i<columns;i++)
{
    System.out.print(temp[i]+"\t");
 }
 System.out.println();
```

replace with

```
System.out.println("This is the sum of the columns");
columnSum(firstarray);
```

Comment: So just add this one into the method?  I tried doing that, but it wasn't displayed properly.  I might be doing something wrong

Comment: Yes.  But it didn't come out like that.  I'll edit above

Comment: So paste this for loop after the code where you are printing the matrix.Not in columnSum method.

Comment: Still not displaying correctly.  Would it be ok if I edited everything above and posted my entire code?

Comment: There is no problem if you enter your full code .but indent that in a good manner means should be readable clearly.

Comment: I made another edit.  I posted the code with some errors.  This one is better

Comment: Now check whether your problem is removed or not.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I just want the total of each column underneath each column and the total for each row to the right of each row.  The code you gave is helpful, but I'm doing something wrong.  I can't get the output I need.

Comment: It's not you, it's me not understanding where to put that code.  I tried putting it where I print (display method) but I get some errors.   Won't compile

Comment: Hey Neuron.  I'm working on totaling the rows, and I figured out the code to total rows. My only problem is I can't display that code to the right of each row.  It displays the total for each row on the bottom like the columns

Answer (score 0):

After printing the array, just print the totals in a single line instead of three lines.

Comment: I'm not following.  I changed println to print, but that doesn't do what I want.

Comment: "but that doesn't do what I want." - and what does it?

Comment: Ok.  I edited to show the output of changing to print

Comment: Yes, perhaps you should omit the hint-text. You didn't print additional text when displaying the array, did you?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a stringbuilder to append each sum to a string and then print it out after the loop is over.

```
StringBuilder columnTotal = new StringBuilder();

for (....){
 columnTotal.append(sum)
}

System.out.println(columnTotal)
```